# Generating key pair directly on Smartcard?

Tags: public-key-encryption, smartcard

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGCrrKsppiQ&feature=player_detailpage#t=80s) claims to be able to generate a key pair directly on the Smartcard so the private key never leaves the card. Is this operation common to all smartcards, or do only select smartcards support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smartcard is just a chip on a card, so you probably want to ask about cryptographic smart cards.

I have never worked with cryptographic smart cards but that sounds like a completely reasonable functionality of such smartcards since they are intended usually for authentication and encryption which usally use private keys for that.

The advantage of cryptographic smart cards usually lies in that, that the private key is stored in it. That is intended to prevent the compromise of the keys because even if the computer, that reads the smartcard, is compromised the smartcard is safe and the private key is safe too.

Comment: Fair enough, but how does one find cryptographic smart cards for sale? I found no reasonable hits when Googling this term. Is it possible **all** smart cards are cryptographic?

Comment: No, not all smartcards have cryptographic functionalities like described in the video. If you want to buy such hardware/software you should google for the purpose you seek, like, "smart card digital signature"

Comment: Googling "smart card digital signature" brings up terrible results (lots of outdated articles with no concrete vendors to buy from). It turns out "cryptographic smart card" works well. Go figure :) "cryptographic smart card price quantity" returns even better results.

Comment: Cool. Please provide feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

Most cryptographic smart cards are able to generate keys in the card in addition to storing externally generated plaintext keys, that's the main purpose of cryptographic smart cards.

Some cards don't allow importing plaintext keys, some allow exporting keys generated on the card, some card can do import/export of wrapped (encrypted with another key) private keys, so that the actual private key would never be in clear in an untrusted environment.

Have a look at http://www.opensc-project.org for a further pointers on cards and software.

Comment: Link seems to be down. The OpenSC project can be found on Github: https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki

Answer (score 0):

this is called on-board key generation, indeed the card generates itself the keys and the private key will never leave the smartcard, besides of the key marked as not exportable, the card itself is unable to export it, it has no function, no knowledge how to do this.

many smartcards ( of course with a cryptoprocessor ) support this but not all and anyway this is  an expensive feature. Most smartcard vendors sell such cards.